# Mapping from page_title to old_text content

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

I try to access the WikiMedia database with a SQL query to fetch the content of an article page.`('old_text', from the 'text' table)` by searching for its page_title `(from the 'page' table)`. 
Unfortunately, I see no mapping between the page_id `(from the page table) an the old_id (from the 'text' table)`.
So, how can I get the text from an article with a sql query, using a given page title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement svick's answer, here's an actual sample SQL query:

```
SELECT old_text, old_flags
FROM page
  JOIN revision ON rev_id = page_latest
  JOIN text ON old_id = rev_text_id
WHERE page_title = 'Main_Page' AND page_namespace = 0;
```

(Note that you'll need the `old_flags` field too to make sense of the content of `old_text`.  At the very least, you should check that the flags field contains the value you expect it to have.)

Comment: Probably should be "you may need the old_flags field" right? On a default installation old_text is uncompressed and contains the actual text of the revision so you wouldn't need old_flags. It's only if you are doing something exotic like compressing old revisions or using shared databases that you would need to do something with old_flags...

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation for the `text` table](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Text_table) says:

> **old_id**
>
> revision.rev_text_id in revision table is a key to this column.

So, to get the text of a certain revision, you need to know the id of the revision you want.
If you want just the latest revision of a page, its id is stored in [`page_latest`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_table#page_latest).

Comment: SELECT old_text from text, page, revision WHERE page.page_latest = revision.rev_id AND revision.rev_text_id = text.old_id and page_title = "<title>" and page_namespace = <namespace id>